# How can I display months in French ? Symfony 6.0.2

Tags: symfony, abstract-data-type, symfony6

I built a registration form in Symfony. I am asking for date of birth to my user. I'd like to know how I can display months in French (or other languages). At the moment they are displayed in English. I posted code on UserType.php. I am thinking maybe I have to add something in it but I have no clue.

How can I display months in French ?

Thank you.

[image: Registration form : months view]

UserType.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CountryType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BirthdayType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\LanguageType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    'Je suis ...' => '',
                    'un homme' => 'male',
                    'une femme' =>'female',
                    'non-binaire' => 'non-binary'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('lastname')
            ->add('firstname')
            ->add('birthdate', BirthdayType::class, [
                'placeholder' => [
                    'year' => 'Année', 'month' => 'Mois', 'day' => 'Jour',
                ],
            ])
            ->add('occupation')
            ->add('nationality', CountryType::class, [
                'placeholder' => 'Choisis un pays',
            ])
            ->add('nativelanguage', LanguageType::class, [
                'placeholder' => 'Choisis ta langue maternelle',
            ])
            ->add('wishedlanguages', LanguageType::class, [
                'placeholder' => 'Choisis une langue étrangère',
            ])
            ->add('email')
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class, [
                'mapped' => false
            ])
            ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'invalid_message' => 'Les deux mots de passe doivent être identiques.',
                'options' => ['attr' => ['class' => 'password-field']],
                'required' => true,
                'first_options'  => ['label' => 'Password'],
                'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat Password'],
            ])
            ->add('roles', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label' => 'Je m\'inscris uniquement en tant qu\'organisateur.',
                'required' => false,
                'compound' => true,
            ])
            ->get('roles')
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                function ($arrayAsBool) {
                return in_array("ROLE_ADMIN", $arrayAsBool);
            },
                function ($boolAsArray) {
                return $boolAsArray ? ["ROLE_ADMIN"] : ["ROLE_USER"];
            }))
            ->add('Subcription', SubmitType::class);
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [BirthdayType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html#choice-translation-domain) supports `choice_translation_domain`, set this to `true`.

```
->add('birthdate', BirthdayType::class, [
    'placeholder' => [
        'year' => 'Année', 'month' => 'Mois', 'day' => 'Jour',
    ],
    'choice_translation_domain' => true
])
```

Update your defaults to set the translation domain name.

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => User::class,
        'translation_domain' => 'forms' // Call it what you like
    ]);
}
```

Then create a translation file, eg: `translations/forms.fr.yaml`. This filename is referencing the `translation_domain` above.

```
# translations/forms.fr.yaml
Jan: Janvier
Feb: Février
Mar: Mars
...
...
```

The language locale `fr` for example, is set in the users request i believe, so you can have as many language translations as you would like. So `forms.de.yaml, forms.es.yaml etc..` and wherever the user is coming from, if the translation matches it will use it.

Comment: I did exactly as you explained. It didn't work. I am probably missing something...

Comment: This should be installed by default but check in your composer file if you have `symfony/translation` installed. If so check, `config/packages/translation.yaml`, is this set `default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'`? Also what is your locale set to?

Comment: On your Symfony profiler bar, there is also a translations menu, clicking this will show if that file is detected at least..

Comment: I have default_locale: en in translation.yaml, so I believe my locale is set to English.

Comment: So to test you could change this to `fr`. What is your operating system set to, French or English?

Comment: I have changed default_locale: en to default_locale: fr. Everything is in French so it's a good thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247764/discussion-between-emilie-tossan-and-bossman).